# How to pick latest file from S3 bucket folder and load into snowflake table using Airflow DAG

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am very new to Airflow DAG and want to pick the latest file from S3 bucket folder and copy into snowflake table.
I am appending current date and time in suffix of each file generated.

```
S3 Bucket : aura-skills-data
Folder : pdl-skills-data/pdl_result_data/

original_df_with_clusters_Fiserv_202309070657.csv
original_df_with_clusters_Mastercard_202309050557.csv
```

As of now I am creating table each time and loading all files.

```
    def upload_file_s3_to_snowflake():
temp_table_stmt = f"""
        CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE {table_name} (INDEX varchar,EMPLOYEE_ID varchar,
        skills varchar,hc varchar,cluster_descr_hc varchar);
        """
    
        temp_table_stmt_result = snowflake_hook.run(temp_table_stmt)
    
        #verify temp table stmt result
        logger.info(temp_table_stmt_result)
    
        copy_stmt = f"""
        COPY INTO {table_name}
        FROM 's3://aura-skills-data/pdl-skills-data/pdl_result_data/' STORAGE_INTEGRATION={storage_integration}
        FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = 'CSV' NULL_IF = ('','NULL') BINARY_FORMAT='UTF-8' FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"' COMPRESSION='NONE' SKIP_HEADER = 1);
        """
```

Answer (score 0):

If the table already exists, you may not need to run the `CREATE TABLE` command. I suspect you can either just run the `COPY INTO` command or look into an existing operator like the [CopyFromExternalStageToSnowflakeOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-snowflake/stable/operators/copy_into_snowflake.html).